# Codeigniter active record - query 3 tables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to make a query using 3 tables and i having some trouble with that.
I have 3 tables in my project:

`projects`, `projects_categories` and `categories`

`projects`

- id_project
- title
- date

`projects_categories`

- id_proj_cat
- id_project
- id_category

`categories`

- id_category
- name

I already made a join query but the result is a array with the same project_id showing several times. 
What i need is a more efficient query that can list for each project_id a array inside, with it´s categories and names. Something like that.

I can make a separate query but im trying to achieve that in one single query.

Comment: its simple join query.what you have tried?

Comment: Yes, i have a long array with the same project appearing several times. What i need is a list of arrays inside of each project array. I can do a separate query... but im trying to achieve that in one single query.

Comment: What you're looking for is unclear from your question. Please show your desired array structure in your question.

Comment: Hello Capt. Jack Sparrow, the structure is like this:

Array (
[0] => Array (
[id_projecto] => 29
[titulo] => Titulo 1
[data] => 2012-12-12
[0] => Array (
[0] => Array (
[id_categoria] => 2
[nome_categoria] => Arquitectura
)
[1] => Array (
[id_categoria] => 3
[nome_categoria] => Reabilitação
)
)
)
[1] => Array (
[id_projecto] => 30
[titulo] => Titulo 2
[data] => 2021-09-12
[0] => Array (
[0] => Array (
[id_categoria] => 3
[nome_categoria] => Reabilitação
)
[1] => Array (
[id_categoria] => 4
[nome_categoria] => Design
)
)
)
)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $this->db->from("projects p");
    $this->db->select("p.id_project,c.categories,c.name");
    $this->db->join("projects_categories pc","pc.id_project = p.id_project","LEFT");
    $this->db->join("categories c","c.id_category = pc.id_category","LEFT");
    $result=$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Now $result is your array.

Comment: Im still facing the same issue. :(

[0] => Array (
[id_projecto] => 29
[titulo] => Titulo 1
[data] => 2012-12-12
[id_categoria] => 2
[nome_categoria] => Arquitectura
)
[1] => Array (
[id_projecto] => 29
[titulo] => Titulo 1
[data] => 2012-12-12
[id_categoria] => 3
[nome_categoria] => Reabilitação
)
[2] => Array (
[id_projecto] => 30
[titulo] => Titulo 2
[data] => 2021-09-12
[id_categoria] => 4
[nome_categoria] => Design
)
[3] => Array (
[id_projecto] => 30
[titulo] => Titulo 2
[data] => 2021-09-12
[id_categoria] => 3
[nome_categoria] => Reabilitação

Comment: if your projects_categories table contains relation with all id_project and if every id_category has name then you can use Inner join.Just replace the word `LEfT`with `INNER`. Other wise select Distinct id_project at your select statement.like `$this->db->select("DISTINCT(p.id_project),c.categories,c.name");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$this->db->select('p.id_project,c.categories,c.name');
$this->db->from('projects p');
$this->db->join("projects_categories pc","p.id_project = pc.id_project","INNER");
$this->db->join("categories c","pc.id_category = c.id_category","INNER");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```